# Need to check validation of an array by another "legal" digits array

Tags: java, arrays

I need to enter number of first numbers array, than input as much numbers as the array length is, than need to ask for length of digits array, and input all the inputs as much as the length.
this part is easy and done fine.
Now I need to check each digit from the number array is appear in the digit array.
if yes print something , else print not[something..]
I've dont it right with numbers < 10
I have a huge problem when it comes to double digits, and I just cant make it work. I've tried several things with many options but still cant find something that work, So I will just post here the last version that working with single digits numbers:

```
int numInNumbersArray,
    tempoNumber=0,
    counterChecks=0,
    digitsCount=0;
    char digitInDigitsArray;
    final char MINUS='-';
    boolean isNegative=false,
            isMinus=false,
            numbersOkay=false;
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the numbers array: ");
    int numbersLength=s.nextInt();
    int[] numbersArray=new int [numbersLength];
    System.out.printf("Please enter %d numbers: ",numbersLength);
        for(int i=0;i<numbersArray.length;i++){
            numInNumbersArray=s.nextInt();
            if(numInNumbersArray<0){
               numInNumbersArray*=-1;
                isNegative=true;
            }
            numbersArray[i]=numInNumbersArray;
            }
    System.out.println("Please enter the length of the digits array: ");
    int digitsLength=s.nextInt();
    char[] digitsArray=new char [digitsLength];
    System.out.printf("Please enter %d digits between 0 - 9 and - if you want: ",digitsLength);
            for(int i=0;i<digitsArray.length;i++){
                digitInDigitsArray=s.next().charAt(0);
                digitsArray[i]=digitInDigitsArray;
                if(digitInDigitsArray==MINUS){
                    isMinus=true;
                }
            }
            if(isMinus!=isNegative){
                System.out.println("Not all numbers are OK.");
            }else{
                for(int i=0;i<numbersArray.length;i++){
                    tempoNumber=numbersArray[i];

                        for(int j=0;j<digitsArray.length;j++){
                            while(counterChecks== 0){
                            if(tempoNumber<10){                         
                                if(tempoNumber==(digitsArray[j]-'0')){
                                   numbersOkay=true;
                                   counterChecks++;
                                }
                                else{
                                    numbersOkay=false;
                                }

                            }else{
                                while(tempoNumber>=10){
                                if(tempoNumber%10==(digitsArray[j]-'0')){
                                   numbersOkay=true;
                                   counterChecks++;
                                }
                                else{
                                    numbersOkay=false;
                                }
                                tempoNumber/=10;
                                }
                        }
                            digitsCount++;
                  }
                }
              }
            if(counterChecks==(digitsCount/digitsArray.length)){
                System.out.println("All numbers are OK.");
                }
                else{
                     System.out.println("Not all numbers are OK.");
                }
            }
```

Im just hopeless now and very confused. I know this method is bad and not working, please someone can help with that, As I mentioned, I have only problem with the double digits and up numbers. So this is where the focus should take place.
advanced thanks. !

Comment: If you had a way to break down a multi-digit number into its individual digits, would that solve your problem?

Comment: obviously thats what I need to do.. thats what im trying to do, and check each time ( one digit from the number) appears in the digit validation array.

Comment: Please explain "does not work": an example, with input, expected and actual output, would be great help.  Actually, knowing what `counterChecks` and `digitsCount` would also be good to know.

Comment: If for example you input for numbers array the number 14 and for digits array numbers 1 and 4 it should be good, if digits array would be 1 and 3 it wouldn't be good... countercheck and digits count is just a way to count each time the is a digit from a number that appears in the digits array, and than compare if both equal its good, But I see now that I have glitch when countercheck not equal to 0 it wont check, so this code is broke. I realy dont know what to do

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check all of the digits in `tempoNumber`, your `while` loop needs to run while `tempoNumber>0`; your current code will not check the last digit.

As for the final result: The logic is that as soon as you find a digit not in your `digitsArray`, you are done: there is at least one digit in one number that is not allowed.  This suggests initializing `numbersOkay` to `true`, and setting it to `false` when you find a bad digit.